# Make a flag wave

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, printable-ascii

Take a flag, like this one:

```
-----------------------------
|             |             |
|             |             |
|=============+=============|
|             |             |
|             |             |
-----------------------------
```

And a number input: the "wave length"

Say the wave length was 5. Then, every 5 characters along the line from the beginning, replace the next character a `-` with `\` and shift all the characters after it one row down. Repeat this until the end. You end up with:

```
-----\
|     -----\
|           -----\
|=====        |   -----\
|     ======  |         -----
|           ==+===          |
-----\        |   ======    |
      -----\  |         ====|
            -----\          |
                  -----\    |
                        -----
```

If you end up not being able to make a full wave length along at the end, the flag is finished. Just remain flat until the end.

You can assume that all the lines are of the same length and that the top and bottom lines are composed entirely of `-` (0x2D) and the rest of the characters are in `` !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ``, or is a space (). (So it's ascii value is `x`, where `31 < x < 127`)
The flag will be at least 3 tall and 3 wide.

Wave length will be a non-negative integer (>= 0).

(You can also have wave length 1 be the smallest wavelength, so the above example would have wave length 6. This is OK.)

Your i/o of flag can be as arrays of lines or a string with multiple lines.

The output flag may have trailing spaces, but can only have leading spaces so long as it is the same on every flag. Trailing space on an input flag may be deleted.

### Scoring

This is code-golf, so the shortest solution, in bytes, wins.

### Test cases

```
---
abc
---
2
--\
abc
--\



-----
| + |
-----
10
-----
| + |
-----



---------------------------------------
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&          .\^/.          &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&        . |   | .        &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&        |\|   |/|        &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&     .--'       '--.     &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&      \           /      &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&       >         <       &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&      '~|/~~|~~\|~'      &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&            |            &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
---------------------------------------
12
------------\                          
|&&&&&&      ------------\             
|&&&&&&                   ------------\
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&          .\^/.          &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&        . |   | .        &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&     .  |\|   |/|        &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&      --'       '--      &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&      \           /.     &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&       >         <       &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&      '~|/~~|~~\|~'      &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&            |            &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
------------\                   &&&&&&|
             ------------\      &&&&&&|
                          ------------\



-----------------------
|-._`-._ :| |: _.-'_.-|
|   `-._`:| |:`_.-'   |
|-------`-' '-'-------|
|------_.-. .-._------|
|  _.-'_.:| |:._`-._  |
|-'_.-'  :| |:  `-._`-|
-----------------------
4
----\
|-._`----\
|   `-._ :----\
|-----._`:| |: ----\
|-------`-| |:`_.-'_---
|  _.--_.-' '-'_.-' .-|
|-'_.-'_.:. .-.-----  |
----\-'  :| |:._------|
     ----\| |: _`-._--|
          ----\ `-._  |
               ----\`-|
                    ---



---------------
---------------
---------------
---------------
---------------
5
-----\         
-----------\   
---------------
---------------
-----\---------
      -----\---
            ---



-------------------------------------------
|*  *  *  *  * |##########################|
| *  *  *  *  *|                          |
|*  *  *  *  * |##########################|
| *  *  *  *  *|                          |
|*  *  *  *  * |##########################|
| *  *  *  *  *|                          |
|*  *  *  *  * |##########################|
|---------------                          |
|#########################################|
|                                         |
|#########################################|
|                                         |
|#########################################|
-------------------------------------------
0
\
|\
|*\
|  \
|** \
|   *\
|**   \
|   ** \
|**    *\
|-  **   \
|#-    ** \
| #-**    *\
|# #-  **   \
| # #-    ** \
\# # #-**    *\
 \# # #-  **   \
  \# # #-    **|\
   \# # #-**   |#\
    \# # #-  **| #\
     \# # #-   |# #\
      \# # #-**| # #\
       \# # #- |# # #\
        \# # #-| # # #\
         \# # #-# # # #\
          \# # # # # # #\
           \# # # # # # #\
            \# # # # # # #\
             \# # # # # # #\
              \# # # # # # #\
               \# # # # # # #\
                \# # # # # # #\
                 \# # # # # # #\
                  \# # # # # # #\
                   \# # # # # # #\
                    \# # # # # # #\
                     \# # # # # # #\
                      \# # # # # # #\
                       \# # # # # # #\
                        \# # # # # # #\
                         \# # # # # # #\
                          \# # # # # # #\
                           \# # # # # # #\
                            \# # # # # # #\
                             \# # # # # # |
                              \# # # # # #|
                               \# # # # # |
                                \# # # # #|
                                 \# # # # |
                                  \# # # #|
                                   \# # # |
                                    \# # #|
                                     \# # |
                                      \# #|
                                       \# |
                                        \#|
                                         \|
                                          \
```

Comment: Expecting @LuisMendo to come here and blow this away within the next day or so.

Comment: Crap... Forgot @ doesn't link those who haven't responded... Someone kick my butt using MATL please so I can delete the comments.

Comment: Anyone animate this

Comment: The first testcase seems to contradict this statement of yours: *If you end up not being able to make a full wave length along at the end, the flag is finished. Just remain flat until the end.*

Comment: @SIGSEGV [Done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120186/56183), though maybe not what you had in mind.

Comment: @KritixiLithos So the rest of the flag (Nothing) goes down, and that nothingness stays flat.

Comment: @carusocomputing Did someone call me? 31 bytes, though

Comment: Is the Canadian flag example wrong? The second shifted column contains a `.` that doesnt shift with the row.

Comment: @Marie It's in the column that has a \\. Only the columns after the \\ shift down.

Comment: Line 9 column 27, it is directly in line with the first `-` of the last turn-downed section.

Comment: @Marie Oh yeah, that's a mistake. I was looking at the wrong dot. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I only noticed it because my solution didnt match and diffchecker highlighted that dot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>25</s> <s>23</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

*-2 thanks to Adnan*

*-1 thanks to Emigna*

*+3 thanks to Jonathan Allan (thanks for spending the time to catch that invalidity!)*

```
øvyN>²Öi¦¨'\.ø}N²÷ú}).Bø»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@394R1mln92hTarxmYeWHVqhHqN3eEet36FNh7cf3lWrqed0eMeh3f//R6vr4gPqOgrqNQrIAI1HnAJbZKCNwquhjhX4fRHLZQQA)

This is 1-indexed instead of 0, +2 bytes if that isn't okay.

```
ø                                    # Transpose.
 vy                }                 # For each column...
   N>²Öi¦¨'\.ø}                      # Replace outside dashes with slants.
               N²÷                   # Current index / input #2.
                  ú                  # Prepend that many spaces to current column.
                    ).Bø             # Join, pad, transpose back.
                        »            # Print with newlines.
```

Emigna/Adnan/Anyone - There HAS to be a better solution to replace those slants, but I'm stumped.

Comment: The 1-indexing is OK.

Comment: `ú` is the same as `ð×ì` :)

Comment: @Adnan that's GOTTA  be new, right? No ideas on "replace last" though? I feel like 05AB1E needs replace first and replace last.

Comment: @JonathanAllan fixed for +3 byte penalty.

Comment: _+3 thanks to Johnathan Allen_ sounds so passive aggressive...

Comment: @Artyer not at all! +3 thanks to him for pointing out my answer wasn't valid, I like it when people actually care enough to read an answer long enough to notice it isn't correct. Did I reword it enough to sound less sarcastic :P?

Comment: @Adnan NO WONDER I CAN NEVER REPLY TO HIM. Sorry about butchering your name *Jonathan Allan*.

Comment: Really not a problem :)

Comment: Very nice answer. Only improvement I can see is `%_` => `Ö`.

Answer (score 9):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 35 bytes

```
j.ts.e+L*k;?qQtlb+PbjPteb*2\\bcC.zh
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j.ts.e%2BL%2ak%3B%3FqQtlb%2BPbjPteb%2a2%5C%5CbcC.zh&input=5%0A-----------------------------%0A%7C+++++++++++++%7C+++++++++++++%7C%0A%7C+++++++++++++%7C+++++++++++++%7C%0A%7C%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%2B%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%7C%0A%7C+++++++++++++%7C+++++++++++++%7C%0A%7C+++++++++++++%7C+++++++++++++%7C%0A-----------------------------&debug=0)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 129 bytes

```python
lambda f,n,j=''.join:map(j,zip(*[i/n*' '+'-\\'[i%n>n-2]+j(s[1:-1])+'-\\'[i%n>n-2]+len(f[0])/n*' 'for i,s in enumerate(zip(*f))]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#3VTRaoMwFH3PV1wsW5I2iev2MJDZHzEO7KYSsamoexkXf72LtoyuoHUPG2OHkIfck5Pc5HDyUB/KZLd9TSATVhQhparYGxvskooV4t1UbBkZ3y4p0BWVWtPI3NiNlffxqmBNtA7kOuaXlTK1LIvuYn7cmO1rMKIBYyG1b7u0TtqUDdIZ5zHnh6xM8gZCiDzPI3IeCN4OgDEcy/jzPKWffXWVpwDdjKCu8FAPPB@neEpKeipTKdW4nj5rwJ86d/NJe5q6H@3Q7zrsOo0dvfp@@Bv/MdMvzlqCnPxFku0LuViTs323BDgbuBiF6wG@kHG0GcD/rXvxiJO6i7no7zsXf0P3Gz5ztowJ6aOzT0cBZR@ffWgOYSkgehTwIMClb0Cgqo1tgWp7TG@WDyyXzrFqqtK0zNPW407Ehe0H)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 29 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
s”\⁹¦€Fð€0,1¦Zsð⁶ẋ;Ð€µ@"J;/z⁶
```

Input and output flags are lists of lines.
Wave length is 1-indexed.
Always produces one line of spaces.
(all of the above is explicitly allowed in the posted question)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@1/8qGFuzKPGnYeWPWpa43Z4A5A00DE8tCyqGMhu3PZwV7f14QlAwUNbHZS8rPWrgGL/H@7ecnh55P//usQBrho1MFDABSDSNbRXpxcTp69HUJ2eQg2QrFHQI6CuJgasTr8Gnzo9XV11qLS6rq4ebvNikDygj89eO7gyG3zuU6@r0a@rq6mri6mpUycYfjX0iA8i08t/Q2MA)** (footer to make IO look pretty - takes and receives flags as multiline text)

#### How?

A pretty similar method to carusocomputing's [05ab1e answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120113/53748), which I have not managed to golf down more.

```
s”\⁹¦€Fð€0,1¦Zsð⁶ẋ;Ð€µ@"J;/z⁶ - Main link: list of lists f, number p
            ¦                 - apply to indexes (of f)
         0,1                  - ... 0 paired with 1 (i.e. last & first -> bottom & top)
       ð€                     - the previous chain with p as right argument for €ach:
s                             -   split into chunks of length p
    ¦€                        -   apply to indexes for €ach
   ⁹                          -   ... link's right argument, p
 ”\                           -   the character '\' (a replacement - if the index is out of bounds this has no effect - although this might change in the future.)
             Z                - transpose the edited flag
              s               - split into chunks of length p
                        J     - range of length = [1,2,...,nChunks]
               ð     µ@"      - zip with reversed arguments (call those i):
                ⁶             -   literal space
                 ẋ            -    repeated i times
                  ;Ð€         -    concatenate mapped across the chunks
                         ;/   - undo the split (reduce with concatenation)
                           z⁶ - transpose with a filler of space characters
```

Comment: Why is it always Jelly that does this?

Comment: 05AB1E clearly won this round!

Comment: OK, why is it always either Jelly or 05AB1E that does this?  (Rhetorical question, I know it's because they're golfing languages)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 31 bytes

```
x"X@q1GQ&\Z"@b1G=?'\'5L(]h]Xhc!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@1@hFOFQaOgeqBYTpeSQZOhua68eo27qoxGbERuRkaz4/7@hEVe0ui5xQN1avUYNDBRwAYh0Db1U6sXE6esRoVJPoQZI1ijoEVRZEwNWqV@DX6UeMDTUoSrUgeGnh8/UGCTP6OO33w6u0Aa/S9XV62r06@pq6upiaupgTsEbpjX0iydi01MsAA) Or verify all test cases:
[1](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@1@hFOFQaOgeqBYTpeSQZOhua68eo27qoxGbERuRkaz4/78pV7S6Lj6gbq1eo4AM0HjEyNsiA20UXg0VzMfv/lgA), 
[2](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@1@hFOFQaOgeqBYTpeSQZOhua68eo27qoxGbERuRkaz4/78RV7S6rq6uurV6YlIykASxYwE),
[3](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@1@hFOFQaOgeqBYTpeSQZOhua68eo27qoxGbERuRkaz4/7@hAVe0ui4IqFur1yhoK9QAaQg/FgA),
[4](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@1@hFOFQaOgeqBYTpeSQZOhua68eo27qoxGbERuRkaz4/7@hEVe0ui5xQN1avUYNDBRwAYh0Db1U6sXE6esRoVJPoQZI1ijoEVRZEwNWqV@DX6UeMDTUoSrUgeGnh8/UGCTP6OO33w6u0Aa/S9XV62r06@pq6upiaupgTsEbpjX0iydi01MsAA),
[5](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@1@hFOFQaOgeqBYTpeSQZOhua68eo27qoxGbERuRkaz4/78JV7S6Lnagbq1eo6sXnwDEClY1CjVWCvF6uurqQKIGJKWgoACSSgBLJYClgEJgKagBCSAhdXUgCRVAkgSq11MA4ngkGQWYBWAjoTZDTQTbC7IB4hKI1WBtuFwfCwA),
[6](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@1@hFOFQaOgeqBYTpeSQZOhua68eo27qoxGbERuRkaz4/78pV7S6LipQt6aSSCwA),
[7](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@1@hFOFQaOgeqBYTpeSQZOhua68eo27qoxGbERuRkaz4/78BV7S6LvFA3Vq9RktBAQnVKOMENSDVCijKaxRwgpqRYzZaoBIwW5lYAHE3sWBwmU1KGowFAA).

Comment: Wow, what was the expensive part? The replacing the `-` with the `[\]`?

Comment: @carusocomputing Yes, I think that's the most expensive part

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>168 164 187 172 167 153 150 152</s> 149 bytes

```php
for($r=count($f=file(a));$y<$r+$e/$n=$argn;$y+=print"
")for($x=0;$x+1<$e=strlen($f[0])-1;)echo("\\".$f[$z=$y-($x/$n|0)][$x++]." ")[$z%($r-1)||$x%$n];
```

takes flag from static file `a` and wave length (minimum 1) from STDIN.
Run as pipe with `php -nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c8b959d44edb1e02b0cc4b04b084b4bf07dd051f).

**breakdown**

```php
for($r=count($f=file(a));       # import file, count lines
    $y<$r+$e/$n=$argn;          # loop $y through lines
    $y+=print"\n")                      # 2. print newline
    for($x=0;$x+1<$e=strlen($f[0])-1;)  # 1. loop $x through columns
    echo("\\".$f[                           # 3. create string=backslash+character+space
            $z=$y-($x/$n|0)                 # 1. line no. = $y - wave offset
        ][$x++]." "                         # 2. pick character from line
        )
    [
        $z%($r-1)                           # if not first or last line
        ||$x%$n                             # or not last position of wave
    ]                                       # then index 1 (character or space), else "\\"
    ;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for lines in the middle: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83b3163b402e0a675bc8bffa419e1424acee2d86

Comment: It shouldn't turn the middle lines into `\`. See the test case after the British one

Comment: It seems to be cutting off some of the bottoms of flags that increase in size a lot:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b6b259e033d3e3d48f9aa23e71dbd6c6dbfcc0c6

Comment: @Artyer That should be it.

Comment: `$z&&$z!=$r-1` should be equivalent to `$z%($r-1)` saving 3 byte.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 175 bytes

```js
f=(s,l,p=++l,t=s.replace(/^-*|-*$/g,s=>s.replace(/-/g,(c,i)=>++i%l?c:`\\`)))=>t.search`
`<p?t:(f(s,l,p+l,t)+`
`+` `.repeat(p)).replace(eval(`/(^|(.*)\\n)(.{${p}})/g`),`
$3$2`)
;
test=(s,l)=>document.write(`<pre>${s}
${l}${f(s,l)}</pre>`);
test(`---
abc
---`,2);
test(`-----
| + |
-----`,10);
test(`---------------------------------------
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&          .\\^/.          &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&        . |   | .        &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&        |\\|   |/|        &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&     .--'       '--.     &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&      \\           /      &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&       >         <       &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&      '~|/~~|~~\\|~'      &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&            |            &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
---------------------------------------`,12);
test(`-----------------------
|-._\`-._ :| |: _.-'_.-|
|   \`-._\`:| |:\`_.-'   |
|-------\`-' '-'-------|
|------_.-. .-._------|
|  _.-'_.:| |:._\`-._  |
|-'_.-'  :| |:  \`-._\`-|
-----------------------`,4);
test(`---------------
---------------
---------------
---------------
---------------`,5);
test(`-------------------------------------------
|*  *  *  *  * |##########################|
| *  *  *  *  *|                          |
|*  *  *  *  * |##########################|
| *  *  *  *  *|                          |
|*  *  *  *  * |##########################|
| *  *  *  *  *|                          |
|*  *  *  *  * |##########################|
|---------------                          |
|#########################################|
|                                         |
|#########################################|
|                                         |
|#########################################|
-------------------------------------------`,0);
```

I/O is as a newline-delimited string. Output includes a leading newline; this can be removed at a cost of 3 bytes. I tried computing the output string directly but that took me... 176 bytes:

```js
f=
(a,l,h=a.length)=>[...Array(h+(a[0].length-1)/++l|0)].map((_,i)=>a[0].replace(/./g,(k,j)=>((k=i-(j/l|0))&&h+~k)|-~j%l?(a[k]||'')[j]||' ':'\\'))
;
test=(s,l)=>document.write(`<pre>${s}
${l}
${f(s.split`
`,l).join`
`}</pre>`);
test(`---
abc
---`,2);
test(`-----
| + |
-----`,10);
test(`---------------------------------------
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&          .\\^/.          &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&        . |   | .        &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&        |\\|   |/|        &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&     .--'       '--.     &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&      \\           /      &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&       >         <       &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&      '~|/~~|~~\\|~'      &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&            |            &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
|&&&&&&                         &&&&&&|
---------------------------------------`,12);
test(`-----------------------
|-._\`-._ :| |: _.-'_.-|
|   \`-._\`:| |:\`_.-'   |
|-------\`-' '-'-------|
|------_.-. .-._------|
|  _.-'_.:| |:._\`-._  |
|-'_.-'  :| |:  \`-._\`-|
-----------------------`,4);
test(`---------------
---------------
---------------
---------------
---------------`,5);
test(`-------------------------------------------
|*  *  *  *  * |##########################|
| *  *  *  *  *|                          |
|*  *  *  *  * |##########################|
| *  *  *  *  *|                          |
|*  *  *  *  * |##########################|
| *  *  *  *  *|                          |
|*  *  *  *  * |##########################|
|---------------                          |
|#########################################|
|                                         |
|#########################################|
|                                         |
|#########################################|
-------------------------------------------`,0);
```

I/O is as a string array.

Comment: It looks like the only test case yours passes is the one that doesnt change.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work properly for most test cases. (The first one was what I tried)

Comment: @Artyer Sorry, that was subtle; I didn't spot the off-by-one error.